# With styled-components, how to use the longform css animation syntax to have multiple keyframed animations?

Tags: javascript, css-animations, styled-components

So when an animation is created via the longform declaration and it has multiple specified names:

```
const animationNameCss = css`
    //insert keyframes here
`

let animatedImg = styled.img`
        animation-name: ${animationNameCss}, ${animationNameCss};
        animation-delay: 0, 200ms;
        animation-duration: 200ms;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
      `;
```

Only the first animation is performed. Is this related to concatenating tagged templates or simply not supported in styled-components? The intent is to create multiple animations that play back to back of 200ms each by concatenating animation-name and animation-delay.

AnimationNameCss is dynamically set to one of 8 different keyframe sets in the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually wrong, it does work like this. The issue was actually in animation-delay: 0, 200ms;

That should be 0ms, 200ms and the animation performs as expected.